# Using rentrez and shiny to download protein sequences

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to R and Shiny. So far I was able to make a script that fetches Protein sequences from ncbi with the rentrez package. However I can't manage to make it work in a shiny application.

I have following input in the ui

```
 sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput("maps.protein.input")
                  ),
```

and in the app file:

```
output$maps.protein.input <- renderUI({
selectInput("prot.accession", "Accession:", as.list(pep.accession))
```

This part works well and it reads the the pep.accession list into the `selectInput`

Now I want to use rentrez to download the protein sequence

```
protein_seq <- reactive({

                    raw_seq <- entrez_fetch(db="protein", id= paste(input$prot.accession), rettype = "fasta")
                    raw_seq <- str_sub(raw_seq, start = str_locate(pattern = "\n", protein_seq)[,1] +1 )
                    str_replace_all(raw_seq, "[\r\n]" , "")

 })
```

In an R script I use:

```
protein_seq <- entrez_fetch(db="protein", id="XP_011524437.1", rettype = "fasta")
protein_seq <- str_sub(protein_seq, start = str_locate(pattern = "\n", protein_seq)[,1] +1 )
protein_seq <- str_replace_all(protein_seq, "[\r\n]" , "")
```

and this code works. I just want to make it interactive.

Comment: You need to provide some reproducible data so that we can help. In your code, for example, what is `pep.accession`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Does it not work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. I have used `XP_011524437.1` in `selectInput` as I do not know what `pep.accession` is. You can change it in your app. I have also corrected the logic in `str_sub` and added a `req()` statement.

```
library(shiny)
library(rentrez)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("maps.protein.input")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("result1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$maps.protein.input <- renderUI({
    selectInput("prot.accession", "Accession:", "XP_011524437.1")
  })

  protein_seq <- reactive({
    req(input$prot.accession)
    raw_seq <- entrez_fetch(db = "protein", id = input$prot.accession, rettype = "fasta")
    raw_seq <- stringr::str_sub(raw_seq, start = str_locate(pattern = "\n", raw_seq)[,1] +1 )
    stringr::str_replace_all(raw_seq, "[\r\n]" , "")
    return(raw_seq)
  })

  output$result1 <- renderText({
    paste0("Protein sequence: ", as.character(protein_seq()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!